# AWS Lambda - Custom Serialization in C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda

Gurus,

I have a pesky problem with a simple AWS C# Lambda function. How to serialize fields with hyphen in their names? For example:

```
{ "detail-type" = "ABC", "event-id" = "123" }
```

If I use the `[assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer))]` it is not able to parse it into a field inside a class like this

```
public class Test
{
     public string DetailType { get; set; }
     public string EventId { get; set; }
}
```

I am not sure if either I can substitute the Deserializer with a different one or if I can add attributes to the Field Property in the class so that it can recognize an hyphenated input field and read it.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out the solution! It seems `Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson` (version 1.7 and beyond) makes use of the [System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json?view=netcore-3.1) namespace! So basically we can use the JsonPropertyName attribute to control the deserialization. I have shown an example below.

**JSON**

```
{ "detail-type" = "ABC", "event-id" = "abc123" }
```

**C# Class**

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

public class Test
{
     [JsonPropertyName("detail-type")]
     public string DetailType { get; set; }

     [JsonPropertyName("event-id")]
     public string EventId { get; set; }
}
```

**Lambda**

```
public string FunctionHandler(Test input, ILambdaContext context)
{
    return "Success!";
}
```